# Need help at coloroma.Fore module in Python

Tags: python, colorama

İ have a code like this:

```
from colorama import Fore as colors

color = input("which color you want?")

print(colors + color)
```

İt says you cant add a str to a AntiFore, so what can i do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Fore is an object you should use it's attributes. For example look below code:

```
from colorama import Fore

print(Fore.RED + 'Color of this sentence is RED.')
```

This link also can be useful to see how to use this library :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-colors-python-terminal/

Comment: İ dont want to use it like this, i want to use color from input. Also i dont have want to do it with if statements